# Android Library : Include properties file within a distributable JAR file

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an Android Library that can be used in different projects, now my problem is I want to include my version.properties in the compiled jar.  However when I compile my library using `gradlew jarRelease` the generated app.jar in **build/libs** folder only contains META-INF folder and my java classes (in packages).

Below is the android portion of my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-test.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        defaultConfig {
                  testInstrumentationRunner   'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        }
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java/'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to attain with my compiled jar is something like this

```
app.jar
\- META-INF
|   \- ....(Files)
\- com
    \- package
        \- sdk
            \- PackageSDK.class
\- resources
   \- version.properties
```

Current what I get is only

```
app.jar
\- META-INF
|   \- ....(Files)
\- com
    \- package
        \- sdk
            \- PackageSDK.class
```

I need to have the resources in my compiled jar.

Comment: How and what is version.properties used?

Comment: I use it for logging, I append the version to my logs' TAG

Comment: Nonetheless, I really need to have the resources file in my compiled jar.

Comment: You can't add resources file in a jar file. Use an aar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a resource file like that, you will probably want to build an aar instead of a jar.  The aar includes all the resources, assets and manifest.

However, consider just defining the variable in your build.gradle and reference it directly from there.

Try using a buildConfigField instead

### mylibrary/build.gradle

```
release {
    buildConfigField "String", "LIB_VERSION", "1.0.1"
}
```

Then access it in code as

```
Log.d(TAG + ":" + BuildConfig.LIB_VERSION, "Something happened");
```

Comment: Just a question, when I compile my library and use it in another project, will this buildConfigField work?

Comment: should remain what it was when the library was compiled.